# Opencart - Calculate price by option field value

Tags: opencart

I looked everywhere.

I have Opencart 2.0.2.0. Some of my products are vegetable. So for them I want to insert 1kg price and give an input field for customers to enter the weight they are after. So 1kg is $29 and if the customer enters "271"g, the price should be "(29/1000)*271 = $7.85. Do you know the easiest way to implement this and pass this dynamic price?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Just pay a developer from the Commercial Support forum:
https://forum.opencart.com/viewforum.php?f=88

Answer (score 0):

This [OpenCart extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=27892) should be able to do it.